# How do I align a CSS arrow at the vertical center of my table cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a CSS arrow and some text in a table cell ...

```
<td><div class="arrow-up"></div> + 1492.46</td>
```

How do I get the arrow to align to the left of the text and also in the vertical center of the cell?  I have tried the below styling on the arrow ...

```
.arrow-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but the arrow is still aligning above the text -- https://jsfiddle.net/s8e5k3st/ .  Any suggestions for getting the proper alignment are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `display:inline-block;` to `arrow-up` class.

```
.arrow-up {
  display:inline-block; /* <-- this */
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Edited JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/s8e5k3st/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to give you an alternative solution, use **Font Awesome**

`<i class="fa fa-caret-up fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

```css
#currencyTable {
  display: inline;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #C7CDD1;
}

.currency-row img,
.currency-row .name {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.currency-row {
  min-height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C7CDD1;
}

.currency-row img,
.currency-row .name {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.currency-row td {
  padding: 12px 0 12px 0;
}

.currency-row td:first-child {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.currency-row td:last-child {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="currencyTable">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Currency</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>1d Change</th>
      <th>1w Change</th>
      <th>1y Change</th>
      <th>% Index Market Cap</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even currency-row">
      <td>Bitcoin</td>
      <td>2727.74 USD</td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-caret-up fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> + 1492.46</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> 53.89 %</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```